# Update if 2 other columns are Equal

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Trigger, is it possible to do the following in a single update?

IF sample.field1 = sample.field2 THEN sample.field3 = 1 ENDIF;

```
UPDATE `sample` SET
`max` = GREATEST(NEW.value, VALUES(max)),
`min` = LEAST(NEW.value, VALUES(min)),

/* THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK */
IF field1 = field2 THEN another_field = 1;


WHERE `id` = NEW.id;
```

1. `field1` , `field2` , `another_field` , `max` , `min` are all columns of the same table named `sample` above.
2. `NEW.value` and `NEW.id` are from another table that runs this trigger.

Right now, I had to add another SELECT and after that another UPDATE to check for this.

Comment: What table do you want to update and what table do you want to store the new record?

Comment: @reds, Updating only 1 table here, edited question for more info as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use something like:

```
UPDATE `sample` SET
`max` = GREATEST(NEW.value, VALUES(max)),
`min` = LEAST(NEW.value, VALUES(min)),   
`another_field` = IF(field1 = field2, 1, `another_field`)
 WHERE `id` = NEW.id;
```

Comment: How do we know the alternative value is zero?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE`:

```
UPDATE `sample` SET
`max` = GREATEST(NEW.value, VALUES(max)),
`min` = LEAST(NEW.value, VALUES(min)),
anotherField = CASE WHEN field1 = field2 THEN 1 ELSE anotherField END;
WHERE `id` = NEW.id;
```

However, I think using two queries is a better way, you only manipulate the records that have to be manipulated using a seperate query.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
set @another_field = 0;
select @fld1 :=field1 ,@fld2:=field2 from sample where id = New.id;
if(@fld1=@fld2) then
@another_field=1;
end if;
/*Execute an update here*/
UPDATE `sample` SET
`max` = GREATEST(NEW.value, VALUES(max)),
`min` = LEAST(NEW.value, VALUES(min)),
your_another_field=@another_field
where id=NEW.id;
```